# magnifier stucks over hyperlink in pdf in uiwebview

Tags: ios7

On viewing pdf in UIWebView, the magnifier gets stuck over the hyperlink and the application freezes.
 Kindly provide some suggestions for the same.

Comment: Its even happening over string format such as http://example.com

Comment: have same problem. `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;` is not called when this happens or any other delegate method. I would be also happy if it would be possible to disable magnifier.

Comment: one more thing application doesn't stuck completely. My application unfreezes when external URL opens my application. What is more interesting when applications stucks all threads call stacks are clear.

Comment: with latest iOS 8.0 beta issue is fixed.